# How to exclude wordpress login register pages from this rewrite rule

Tags: php, wordpress, .htaccess, url-rewriting

I am using wordpress for my website.in root directory
to remove query string from wesites url

I am using this code

```
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} .
RewriteRule ^$ /? [R=301,L]

RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} \?
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} .+
RewriteRule .? %{REQUEST_URI}? [R=301,L]

RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^(GET|HEAD|POST)\ /[^\ \?]*\?($|\ )
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /$1? [L,R=301]
```

but now problem is that

```
wp-login.php?action=lostpassword

wp-login.php?action=register
```

this urls also redirecting to parent url

I tried excude wp-login.php file from this rule but didn work.

How to solve this issue?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add the following rule above your existing rules :

```
RewriteRule ^wp-login\.php$ - [L]
```

This tells the engine to pass /wp-login.php without rewriting.